# inserting elements into List during Iteration in TCL/TK Scripting

Tags: scripting, tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to add each input integer into a list and later sort it however I am having trouble adding each integer into the list during iteration.

code:

```
set l1 {1 2 3 4 5}

for {set i 0} {$i<[llength $l1]} {incr i} {
   set data [gets stdin]
   scan $data "%d" myint

   if $myint<=0 {break} # stop if non positive number is found

   set l1 {$myint} # supposed to add an input element into the list during iteration

}

puts $l1
```

Comment: The answer is here: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lappend.htm

Comment: Also, [brace your expressions](http://wiki.tcl.tk/10225): `if {$myint <= 0} {break}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an element to the end of a list is easy; just use [`lappend`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lappend.htm) instead of `set`:

```
lappend l1 $myint
```

When you come to sorting the list later, use [`lsort -integer`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lsort.htm), for example here with the `puts`:

```
puts [lsort -integer $l1]
```

(The `lsort` command works on values, not variables like `lappend`.)

---

However, it appears you're trying to actually input up to five values and sort those. If that's so, you'd be better off writing your code like this:

```
set l1 {}
for {set i 0} {$i < 5} {incr i} {
    set data [gets stdin]
    if {[eof stdin] || [scan $data "%d" myint] != 1 || $myint <= 0} {
        break
    }
    lappend l1 $myint
}
puts [lsort -integer $l1]
```

The differences here? I'm using an empty initial list. I'm testing for End-Of-File. I'm checking the result of `scan` (in case someone supplies a non-integer). I'm using a compound expression. It's all little things, but they help the code be more robust.